# How to use Pyautogui in centos Docker to automate the UI and where to download the linux dependencies of pyautogui

Tags: pyautogui

How can I use Pyautogui in centos Docker to automate the UI?  Also where can I download the linux dependencies of `pyautogui` (like `scrot`)?